# Do I need to free something in a linked list in C that has been malloced if I freed the entire node?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, linked-list, dynamic-memory-allocation, free

So I was writing a program with linked lists in C and I was using the free function and I was wondering why this does not create a segmentation fault because I didn't free name. Is it because the free function automatically frees name in its process?

Consider some of my code:

```
typedef struct node{
        char *name;
    struct node *next;
} Node;

//and in main for instance,
Node* newNode = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
char* name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*)*((size_t)numofchar+1)); //numofchar is #of char in string 
newNode->name = name;

//and when freeing somehow when not freeing name it doesn't create segfault, so I simply wrote
free(newNode);
```

so somehow not writing free(newNode->name) doesn't create a segfault, why is that? Is this a special quality of the free() function or something unusual happened and I'm supposed to free it?

Comment: why do you expect your code to produce a seg fault?

Answer (score 0):

For starters it seems you mean at least

```
char* name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*((size_t)numofchar+1)); //numofchar is #of char in string
```

instead of

```
char* name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*)*((size_t)numofchar+1)); //numofchar is #of char in string
```

That is you need to allocate an array of elements of the type `char` instead of the pointer type `char *`.

Your code produces a memory leak because the memory allocated for the character array was not freed.

Before freeing the memory allocated for the entire node you need to free the memory allocated for the character array

```
//and when freeing somehow when not freeing name it doesn't create segfault, so I simply wrote
free( newNode->name );
free(newNode);
```

Comment: Thank you, I was wondering that because somehow no segfault was producedwhen not writing free(newNode->name); but I guess I have to write it.  I thought maybe free automatically frees newNode->name

Comment: @Wolfking free frees only the memory pointed to by the pointer passed to the function. The function knows nothing how the allocated memory was used. It deals with a pointer of the type void *.  A segfault can occur if you will pass to the function a pointer that does not point to a previously allocated memory.

Comment: If you don't free the memory, it does not produce `segfault` instead it produces `memory leak`